# Is there an augeas lens, that can edit perl hash like in .gitolite.rc?

Tags: perl, gitolite, augeas

I want to edit the gitolite3`s configuration file, which is written in perl, and looks like that:

```
# comments

# comments

%RC = (

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------

    # comments
    UMASK                           =>  0077,

    # comments
    GIT_CONFIG_KEYS                 =>  '',

    # comments
    ROLES => {
        READERS                     =>  1,
        WRITERS                     =>  1,
    },

    # comments
    ENABLE => [

        # comments

            'help',
            'desc',
            'info',
            'perms',
            'writable',

        # comments

    ],

);

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# comments
1;

# comments
```

If no augeas is available I need something that preserve the comments - they are very handy for me and future admins.

Comment: @ialarmedalien I need it in a script, that will be used in an automated gitolite deployment

Answer (score 2):

Since gitolite.rc is directly an associative array, you could consider writing your utility in perl.

[`src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm) already show you how to load that file, and it [provides a way to query the keys/values](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/dc8b590a0562ab7dc4bdab9511fe6c31cb422ae8/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L352-L357):

```
Usage: gitolite query-rc -a
gitolite query-rc [-n] [-q] rc-variable
-a print all variables and values (first level only)
-n do not append a newline if variable is scalar
-q exit code only (shell truth; 0 is success)
```

But you can extends those features with a way to add key/value and write the config back.

Comment: Good advise if I only knew Perl. But still - I suspect that if I am ready to skip the comments I might relatively easily do something like `dump` the modified hash back to disk. But I prefer to leave the comments intact - they  are very handy for me and any future admin. That's way I turned my attention towards augeas.